# Where can I find my Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have Windows 7. Every day I used Outlook. To start this program I used a shortcut on my desktop. To create this shortcut I pressed "Start" button, then "All programs", then opened folder "Microsoft Office", then found "Outlook" there and took it from there to my Desktop.

Yesterday I deleted my shortcut on the desktop. And, what is strange, I cannot see outlook through the "Start" menu.

So, what can I do now? Where can I find my outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default installatrion path is c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\outlook.exe
You can create a shortcut from the .exe file and place it in your start menu and on your desktop.

Otherwise search for outlook.exe using search.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joe. It helps. I was able to run outlook from the command prompt. I still need to find out how to make a shortcut but at least I can run the outlook.

Comment: In Windows explorer open the C Drive. Navigate through the folders to Program Files\microsoft office\office12.

In that folder will be a file named Outlook.exe. Right click on this file and select create shortcut.
This will create a shortcut in this folder.
Drag this shortcut to the desktop and into your start menu.
Let me know if this doesn't work for you.